# How to link Android Developer merchant account to an existing Google merchant checkout account

Tags: android, google-checkout

I would like to know how can I link an Android Developer merchant account with an existing Google checkout account. During the creation of the Android Developer merchant account, I only see the option to create a new google checkout account - I don't see a way to link to an existing google check out account.

Does anyone know if this is possible? If so, can you tell me how to do it? The google developer documentation doesn't explicitly say it's *not* possible.

Answer (score 0):

In order to Link your Adsense account to your Developer account you MUST create first a Google Checkout Account.
After creating one, you will see on your developer console a new request to link between your account to your adsense (by entering your pub-xxxxxxxxxxx  id).

Comment: Thank you for your response, but the option that you mentioned above is making you to create a new google checkout account, which I would like to avoid. I would like to link it to an existing google checkout account.